# fastest way to check web-services availability

Tags: php, json, web-services, curl

My application uses about 70 external services. On init function I want to test if all of them are avaliable and can produce json. I was trying to do that via `curl`, via parallel `curl`, but always if some service is unavaliable I have to wait all timeout (5 sec) so in worst case my script will hang for `70 * 5` seconds which is not good for init function in application. Maybe someone have better idea?

my code with strict curl:

```
foreach ($services as $key => $value) {
  $url = $value['url'] . '?f=json';
  $curl = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.2) Gecko/20090729 Firefox/3.5.2 GTB5');
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

  $result = curl_exec($curl);
  $result2 = json_decode($results, TRUE);

  if ($result != FALSE && gettype($result) !== "integer"
      && !array_key_exists('error', $result)) {
         $avaliableServices[$key] = TRUE;

  }
}
```

I was trying to modify timeout value, but 5sec is the optimum value in my example..

and same version of code but with parallel curl:

```
$i = 0;
$running = null;
$output = array();
$curlArray = array();
$master = curl_multi_init();


for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
  $curlArray[$i] = curl_init($urlArray[$i]);
  curl_setopt($curlArray[$i], CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
  curl_setopt($curlArray[$i], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($curlArray[$i], CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.2) Gecko/20090729 Firefox/3.5.2 GTB5');

  curl_multi_add_handle($master, $curlArray[$i]);
}

do {
  curl_multi_exec($master, $running);
} while($running > 0);

foreach ($curlArray as $key => $value) {
  $result = curl_multi_getcontent($value);
  $result2 = json_decode($results, TRUE);

  if ($result != FALSE && gettype($result) !== "integer"
      && !array_key_exists('error', $result)) {
             $avaliableServices[$key] = TRUE;
  }
}
```

I'm wondering if there is fastest way?

Comment: Just do a simple HTTP get on the URL of the service and check the response code.

Comment: this still doesnt reslove the problem, becouse 70 http get requests with 5sec timeout is not good performance.